# How to read back a file written using Data::Dumper (but not with the default VAR naming)?

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I have written a hash structure into a file using

```
print FILE Data::Dumper->Dump([$x], [ qw(*x) ]);
```

How do I read this back from file? If I use eval as shown in the following snippet, all I get is $VAR1 = undef;

```
local $/; $hash_ref = eval <FILE>;
```

Comment: Why would you use backticks around that statement? `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: If you really have backticks around that code in your source code, then the answer is that when using backticks, that string is sent to your shell and evaluated as a shell command. Any variables will be interpolated, and no perl code is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the core module **[Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html)** to do this type of task.

```
use Storable;
store \%table, 'file';
$hashref = retrieve('file');
```

Comment: There are plenty of formats suitable for serializing data, but I don't think `Data::Dumper` is one of them.

Comment: @srk What do you mean by readable? Keep in mind that you have to use the `retrieve` function, with the name of the file where your data is located as argument, to recreate that same data structure in memory again.

Comment: ya i agree that Data::Dumper is not the way to go about it.

Answer (score 4):

If those two statements are in the same file, then you can't do it that way unless you close the file handle and reopen the same file for reading. You could do something fancy like opening it with mode `+>` and then using `seek` to get back to the beginning before you read again, but why bother, especially since you already have a variable in the same program that contains the same data.

So I assume you are dumping the data from one program and reading it again in another. The problem with using `Data::Dumper->Dump([$x], ['*x'])` is that it will dereference `$x` and invent a variable of the appropriate type with the given name. So if `$x` is a hash reference it will name the variable `%x`, if it is an array reference then it will be `@x` etc.

It is far better to remove the star and just write `Data::Dumper->Dump([$x], ['x'])`, which will avoid the dereferencing and name the variable `$x`.

To read the file back in you should just use `do`. Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $x = {
  a => 1,
  b => 2,
};

open my $fh, '>', 'dumper.txt' or die $!;
print $fh Data::Dumper->Dump([$x], ['x']);
close $fh;

my $data = do 'dumper.txt';
```

If you are constrained to using the form of `Data::Dumper` call that you show, then you must provide a variable of the appropriate type, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $x = {
  a => 1,
  b => 2,
};

open my $fh, '>', 'dumper.txt' or die $!;
print $fh Data::Dumper->Dump([$x], ['*x']);
close $fh;

my %data = do 'dumper.txt';
```

Note that, although the `Data::Dumper` output file refers to a variable `%x`, the file is run as a separate Perl program and there is no `%x` in the program that executes the `do`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several ways to export an existing hash.  The only way I found that works is to create a new var that is a pointer to the existing hash.
Then Borodin's answer works well.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %x = (
  a => 1,
  b => 2,
);

my $x = \%x;  # <<< Added so $x is a reference to %x.
open my $fh, '>', 'dumper.txt' or die $!;
print $fh Data::Dumper->Dump([$x], ['*x']);
close $fh;

my %data = do 'dumper.txt';
```